# validate textbox to accept numbers only upto 8 places

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a text box where phone number must be entered I want to limit the digits to be entered in the text box only upto 8 places how to do it?

Comment: Have you considered using a MaxedTextBox?

Comment: If you are just wanting to limit the amount of characters use the MaxLength Property.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe for the `KeyDown` event to see which key is pressed, then just allow <kbd>Numeric</kbd> & <kbd>backspace key</kbd>

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.MaxLength = 8
    AddHandler TextBox1.KeyDown, AddressOf HandleTbKeyDown


End Sub

Private Sub HandleTbKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
    If Not ((e.KeyValue >= 48 AndAlso e.KeyValue <= 57) OrElse e.KeyValue = 46) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For text box having only numbers you can do by this:-

```
if(!((e.keyCode>=48&&e.keyCode<=57)||(e.keyCode==46)))
```

Also you can check the length to 8 like

```
Texbox MaxLength = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a MaskedTextBox. See this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/maskedtextbox-in-C-Sharp/). Though the example is for C# it will work similarly. Your **Mask** property will be **00000000**

for e.g.

```
myMaskTextBox.Mask = "00000000";
```

You can use it format data for dates, currencies etc. Also there is a handy **BeepOnError** property. Again see at the end of example.